# Prove the real-version of Riemann–Lebesgue lemma

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

I've been told to prove the real-version of Riemann–Lebesgue lemma, which is: for $f$ integrable and $2\pi$ periodic:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\cos(nx) \ dx =  \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\sin(nx) \ dx =0$$

Now, previously we proved this theorem for the complex version by finding an appropriate step-function, $g(x)$ (Which we know that is an integrable function) such that:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} |f(x)-g(x)|\ dx < \varepsilon$$

The rest is easy.

Now, technically I could repeat the same proof only looking at $\cos(nx), \sin(nx)$  instead of $e^{-inx}$. Is that what I'm suppose to do? or there is a better and neat way proving it.

Comment: The two alternatives are to repeat the proof or to deduce the real version _from_ the complex version. Nobody here can say which one is the one you're supposed to do. (You see how the real version follows from the complex version?)

Comment: I'm surprised that I just found this question right 1 year later when you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, Riemann-Lebesgue lemma told us : 
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}\ dx\rightarrow0\ \text{as }n\rightarrow\infty
$$
for integrable $2\pi$-periodic function $f$.

Then just take Real and Imaginary part of left hand side which is
: 
$$
\text{Re}\left(\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}\ dx\right)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\text{Re}\left(e^{-inx}\right)\ dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)\ dx.
$$
And 
$$
\text{Im}\left(\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}\ dx\right)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\text{Im}\left(e^{-inx}\right)\ dx=-\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)\ dx.
$$